# Controller not called.. No error on console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my html code

```
<!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">


      <!-- Main row -->
      <div class="row">




        <!-- Left col -->
       <div class="col-sm-9">


          <div class="box box-danger">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
             <!-- <h3 class="box-title" style="font-size:13px">Variance Capacity Forecast[t-1] vs. Actual)</h3>-->
              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
               <!-- POP UP MODAL -->

               <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
                    <button ng-click="toggleModal('Success')" class="btn btn-default">Add Client</button>
                    <!-- Any additional data / buttons  inside the modal -->
                    <modal visible="showModal">
                       <!-- FORM --> 
                       <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller = "formCtrl">
                            <div>
                                <label for="name">Client ID:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="client_id" ng-model="formData.id"/>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <label for="name">Client Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="client_name" ng-model="formData.name"/>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <label for="status">Status:</label>
                                <select ng-model="formData.statuses" ng-options="x for x in statuses">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <label for="date">Update Time:</label>
                                <input id="date" ng-value="TimeStamp">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <label for="updt_by">Update By:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="updt_by" ng-model="formData.updt_by"/>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <label for="updt_id">Update Id:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="updt_id" ng-model="formData.updt_id"/>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <label for="cluster">Cluster:</label>
                                <select ng-model="formData.cluster" ng-options="x for x in cluster">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit
                                 </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </modal>

               <!-- TABLE --> 
               <div ng-controller = "clientCtrl">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center">

                    <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Client_ID</th> 
                        <th style="text-align:center">Client_Name</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Status</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Updt_Time</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Updt_By</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Updt_ID</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center">Cluster</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="i in client">
                        <td>{{i.Client_ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Client_Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Status}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Updt_Time}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Updt_By}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Updt_ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.Cluster}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.col (LEFT) -->
   </div>
 </section>
```

it has a total of three controllers 
1) MainCtrl 
2)FormCtrl
3)ClientCtrl

and the controller code is as given below

```
clientApp.controller('clientCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$document',        function($scope, $http,$document) {
    alert("Inside client control");
   var refresh=function(){
  $http.get('/client').success(function(response) {
  $scope.client = response;

    });
    };
      refresh();
 }]);

clientApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.buttonClicked = "";
    $scope.toggleModal = function(btnClicked){
    $scope.buttonClicked = btnClicked;
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

clientApp.controller('formCtrl',function($scope,$http){
      $scope.statuses = ["Active", "Inactive"];
      $scope.cluster = ["East Coast","West Coast","PayPal"]
      //Date time field values
      var currentTime = new Date()
      var yr=currentTime.getFullYear()
      var mnth=currentTime.getMonth()
      var dt=currentTime.getDate()
        if (mnth < 10) {
        mnth = "0" + mnth
        }
        if (dt < 10) {
        dt = "0" + dt
        }

    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

     if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
     }
     if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds
     }
     $scope.TimeStamp = yr + "-" +mnth+ "-" + dt + " " + hours + ":" +  minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";


       //when submit button is clicked 
       $scope.submit = function() {

            alert($scope.formData.name);
           /* $http.post('/api/stickies', $scope.formData)
                            **** somehow assign data to something useable by    the function below???******

                    })
                    .error(function(data){
                            console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });*/
    };
  });
  clientApp.directive('modal', function () {
     return {
       template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
        '<div class="modal-content">' + 
          '<div class="modal-header">' + 
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-    hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ buttonClicked }} clicked!!</h4>' + 
          '</div>' + 
          '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
        '</div>' + 
      '</div>' + 
    '</div>',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace:true,
  scope:true,
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      if(value == true)
        $(element).modal('show');
      else
        $(element).modal('hide');
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });
  }
};
});
```

Now the alert box in the controller "clientCtrl" is not called.. The code seems to skip the entire div which calls the 'clientCtrl'

Comment: Please provide a plunker that reproduce exact same issue

Comment: Lose the spaces in `ng-controller = "clientCtrl"` (`ng-controller="clientCtrl"`)

Comment: Maybe you forget to add the ng-app attribute in your HTML ?

Comment: and another thing is not to use `alert()` in you angular code ! it may destroy every thing

Comment: i removed the spaces in ng-controller still not working @devqon

Comment: Is it possible that you have not included al your js files in your index.html file ? I have gotten a similar (no error) situation where I forgot to add some script tags

Comment: other controllers works fine i have added ng-app attribute to my html tag @R.Foubert

Comment: Can you post the updated code after adding ng-app?? and did you include angular.js ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only situation that I can imagine where everything else works but your client controller is not detected and no error is when the js file where you have written the clientCtrl is not added or loaded on the page where you have

```
<div ng-controller = "clientCtrl">
```

As a test add this on your html page:

```
<script>

app.controller('clientCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$document',        function($scope, $http,$document) {
    alert("Inside client control");
   var refresh=function(){
  $http.get('/client').success(function(response) {
  $scope.client = response;

    });
    };
      refresh();
 }]);
</script>
```

if everything works after this.

Add the js file to your index page by doing

```
<script src="yourClientControllerFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: All the other controllers are also on the same controller file and i have added it to my html page.. :/ but something else is going wrong here.. i m perplexed..

Comment: Does it work when you manually add the script on the html page where you have <div ng-controller = "clientCtrl"> ?

Comment: No it doesn't work even if i add the script on the same html page :(

Comment: Thank you i found the error ! it was because i didnt close my <select> statements on the form ! :|

Answer (score 1):

Did you give path of clientCtrl file in index header.
Like

```
<script src="ClientCtrl"></script>
```